# dnsmasq, hostapd and virtual hosts on a Single Machine

Tags: server, apache-httpd, dns

I have a raspberry pi setup with dnsmasq, hostapd and apache. I am trying to get dnsmasq to point to virtual hosts so I can make a portable intranet with multiple sites. I have the same setup at home, but with the router and access point wifi on a different machine to the apache server, and that works fine.

But with the single machine setup any url that I put in for a site on the local network just returns 127.0.0.1.

Comment: If you don't want dnsmasq to read /etc/hosts `no-hosts` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Onwards to portable intra-net!

Comment: Nice, I added my comment as a answer so this Q can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want dnsmasq to read `/etc/hosts` add `no-hosts` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`